# How do I append LINQ queries to each other?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a form that filters the data depending on what they select.

I am trying to append linq queries to each other so that the end result is what they have selected on the screen.

Here is my code:

```
private void button_Search_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  using (var model = new SuburbanPortalEntities())
  {
    var qry = from logs in model.Logs
              select logs;

    Guid corpid;
    if (Guid.TryParse(textBox_CorporationGuid.Text, out corpid))
    {
      qry = from logs in model.Logs
                where logs.CorporationId == corpid
                select logs;
    }

    Guid tokenid;
    if (Guid.TryParse(textBox_TokenId.Text, out tokenid))
    {
      qry = from logs in model.Logs
            where logs.TokenId == tokenid
            orderby logs.LogDateTime descending 
            select logs;
    }

    if (checkBox_DisplayErrors.Checked)
    {
      qry = from logs in model.Logs
            where logs.IsException
            select logs;
    }

    if (checkBox_DisplayWarnings.Checked)
    {
      qry = from logs in model.Logs
            where logs.IsWarning
            select logs;
    }

    dataGridView1.DataSource = qry;


  }
}
```

I'm having no luck. The last qry in is what is displayed on my datagridview.

Can someone show me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks !

Comment: From your 2nd query, you can query from the result returned from the previous query.

Comment: You are overriding the variable `qry` with a new result each time, not unlike doing `int a = 0; a = 1;`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What's happening here is that you're redefining `qry` from your source data each time. `qry` is an `IEnumerable<T>` just the same as `logs`, so you should be able to replace your code like so:

```
 var qry = model.Logs;

 if( // Condition )
    qry = qry.Where(x => x.CorporationId == corpId);

 if( // Another condition)
    qry = qry.Where(x => x.IsException);
```

At the end of this setup, `qry` will be the composition of all the selected `Where` clauses and should produce just the items you are looking for.

Comment: `qry` is an `IQueryable<T>`, not an `IEnumerable<T>`.  (Although `IQueryable<T>` inherits from `IEnumerable<T>`.)  It's a very important distinction.

Answer (score 6):

You can use linq [`Concat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb302894.aspx):

```
qry = qry.Concat(
            from logs in model.Logs
            where logs.CorporationId == corpid
            select logs);
```

On the other hand, you may want to create query based on your conditions which will select appropriate results, so you will query your data source once.

Comment: The OP probably wants [Concat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb302894.aspx) (which appends the results) rather than Union (which performs a set union)

Comment: Thanks, I've edited my answer to include `Concat` method as this indeed may be what OP wants.

Comment: Note that, depending on the specifics involved, using `Concat` won't necessarily involve two DB queries.  The queries can be combined by the query provider and result in a single query sent to the database.

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend using the Predicate Builder function in [LinqKit](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx). You can append additional search parameters using And and Or methods.

I used it for exactly this purpose and worked really well.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Concat:

```
private void button_Search_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  using (var model = new SuburbanPortalEntities())
  {
    var qry = (from logs in model.Logs
              select logs).ToList();

Guid corpid;
if (Guid.TryParse(textBox_CorporationGuid.Text, out corpid))
{
  qry.Concat((from logs in model.Logs
            where logs.CorporationId == corpid
            select logs).ToList());
}

Guid tokenid;
if (Guid.TryParse(textBox_TokenId.Text, out tokenid))
{
  qry.Concat(from logs in model.Logs
        where logs.TokenId == tokenid
        orderby logs.LogDateTime descending 
        select logs).ToList());
}

if (checkBox_DisplayErrors.Checked)
{
  qry.Concat((from logs in model.Logs
        where logs.IsException
        select logs).ToList());
}

if (checkBox_DisplayWarnings.Checked)
{
  qry.Concat((from logs in model.Logs
        where logs.IsWarning
        select logs).ToList());
}

dataGridView1.DataSource = qry;
```

}
}