# Appending .Where(..) to a Linq.IQueryable

Tags: c#, linq

I am building a `Linq IQueryable` and want to add a different `.Where()` argument depending on a certain condition. At runtime the appended `.Where()` doesn't seem to be taken into account. What could be done wrong?

```
var query = Context.Sessions
   .Where(s => s.UserID.Equals(currentUserID))
   .Where(s => s.ClosedTime.HasValue)
   .Where(s => !s.ApprovedTime.HasValue);

if (type == Models.EnvironmentType.A)
{
   query.Where(s => s.BedroomID.HasValue);
}
else if (type == Models.EnvironmentType.B)
{
   query.Where(s => s.HomeID.HasValue);
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I append linq queries to each other](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18149153/how-do-i-append-linq-queries-to-each-other)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to assign  returning result back to the query.`Where` creates a new query, it doesn't change the original one.

```
query = query.Where(s => s.BedroomID.HasValue);
```

Answer (score 1):

`query.Where(s => s.BedroomID.HasValue)` is only going to yield a query, it will not alter the existing `query`.

You need to assign it to the existing query:

```
query = query.Where(s => s.BedroomID.HasValue);
```

Comment: Well, looks like I should have updated before submitting this.  lol